# NSIS command sequencing

Tags: nsis

Some background:

Previous installers have worked OK, But I now have a customer who insists that a user logs into an account that has "install" privileges, so writing data to the installer's directory doesn't work when the user logs back in as usual.

I want my installer to:
Install files to $PROGRAMFILES
Look in $PROGRAMFILES for UserDirectory.txt (contains the full path for User Files - this is used by the .exe)

If UserDirectory.txt exists then
exit (it's a reinstall - UserDirectory.txt is fine)
else
It's a new installation
Open a dialog that will allow the user to select a directory for User Files
Write the response to UserDirectory.txt
Write the User Files

My code to date is here
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiVf8kLyta3Hpj-OCYAoQt5QpQ-2?e=HLUy2N
(please laugh quietly!)

I had thought that

```
Install the program

Ask the user where to put the user data
```

was a really simple idea.  Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This design sounds incorrect, no files in $PROGRAMFILES should contain a user specific path because the applications installed in $PROGRAMFILES are shared by all users on the machine.

Ignoring that, your code contains multiple issues with the largest one being a problematic usage of $InstDir/$ProgramFiles/$ProgDataDir in strange combinations.

A basic installer should look like this:

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"
;InstallDirRegKey ...

!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir ; Set File destination
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\uninstall.exe"
File MyApp.exe
File /r "Template"
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
...
SectionEnd
```

`InstallDir` sets the default value for $InstDir. `MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY` gives the user a chance to change $InstDir. After that page, you should only refer to $InstDir, not $ProgramFiles or any other variable.

An installer that uses `RequestExecutionLevel admin` should not touch $PROFILE/$APPDATA/$LOCALAPPDATA because you are doing an install for all users and UAC might run the installer as a different user with a different profile.

If you have some kind of template data that is specific to each user, the application, not the installer should copy the template/initial data from $InstDir to $AppData!

> [Certification requirements for Windows desktop apps](https://web.archive.org/web/20140725202245/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh749939.aspx)
>
> - 10 Apps must install to the correct folders by default
> - 10.1 Your app must be installed in the Program Files folder by default
>   For native 32-bit and 64-bit apps in %ProgramFiles%, and
>   %ProgramFiles(x86)% for 32-bit apps running on x64. **User data or app
>   data must never be stored in this location because of the security
>   permissions configured for this folder.**
> - 10.6 **Your app must write user data at first run and not during the installation in “per-machine” installations**
>   **When the app is installed, there is no correct user location in which
>   to store data.** Attempts by an app to modify default association
>   behaviors at a machine level after installation will be unsuccessful.
>   Instead, defaults must be claimed on a per-user level, which prevents
>   multiple users from overwriting each other's defaults.

If you want to ignore this advice, here is basic version that goes against the Microsoft guidelines:

```
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"
;InstallDirRegKey ...

Var UserDataDir
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Blah blah"
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Blah blah. Blah blah."
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE $UserDataDir
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function .onInit
StrCpy $UserDataDir "$AppData\MyApp" ; Default
FunctionEnd

Section

SetOutPath $InstDir
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\uninstall.exe"
File MyApp.exe

SetOutPath $UserDataDir
File Template.txt

SetDetailsView show
SetAutoClose false
DetailPrint AppInstall=$InstDir
DetailPrint UserData=$UserDataDir
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
...
SectionEnd
```